# Translation for "Wow, I can't believe it!"

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to translate something like:

> "Wow, that's amazing! I cannot almost believe it!"

What would be the best and most common German way to say that?

Comment: @c.p.: As much as prior research effort is desirable we should not be too picky on that.

Comment: Another observation is this: Imagine somebody searches for `"I can't believe it" german` by Google - it is so great to see us appear on the [top 5 search results](https://www.google.de/search?q="I+can't+believe+it"+german).

Answer (score 3):

> Kaum zu glauben!
>   Unglaublich!
>   Kaum zu fassen!
>   Irre!

Jugend-Slang kenne ich nicht so gut. Da dürfte es noch so manche neueren Sprüche geben.

(edited)

Answer (score 2):

> Wow, das ist fantastisch! Ich kann's fast nicht glauben!

Edit:

What I personally would rather say (as a young adult):

> Das gibt's nicht!
>   Das glaub ich nicht!
>   Krass!
>   Der Wahnsinn!

Answer (score -2):

> Holla, das ist frappierend! Ich kann es nicht fast glauben!

Comment: "Frappierend"? Wo hast du das Wort ausgepackt?

Comment: @Em1, ich behaupt jetzt einfach, dass wir das in Berlin so sagen und die Hugenotten schuld sind :)

Comment: @Emanuel Ich kann es nicht fassen, dass du einen Upvote für einen grammatikalisch falschen Satz verteilst.

Comment: @Em1... das war als Scherz gemeint. Ich bin sicher, dass Carsten diese Antwort nicht stehen lassen wird, jetzt wo es so aussieht, als bleibe die Frage offen. Den Grammatikfehler hab' ich aber offen gestanden nicht gesehen. Eigentlich ist es ja auch nicht falsch. Zumindest grammatisch nicht "Ich konnte es nicht fast glauben, sondern voll und ganz." Läuft ;)

Comment: @Em1... just occurred to me... the question has the same weird positioning of "almost"

Comment: @Emanuel Ich bin des Englischen ja nicht wirklich mächtig, aber zumindest "I can't quite believe it" müsste richtig sein. "Almost" würde ich tatsächlich nach vorne setzen "I almost can't believe it", falls ich es überhaupt jemals so sagen würde. Aber die Regel die zumindest in der Frage beachtet wurde war: Adverb vor das Verb bzw. zwischen Hilfsverb und Verb.

Comment: Es scheint, als hätte das „frappierend“ von dem zweiten Satz, um den es mir eigentlich ging, abgelenkt. Ich denke, er ist eine genaue Übersetzung des Englischen. Natürlich ist er in dem Sinne, den Emanuel angibt, Unsinn. Vielleicht ist das im Englischen trotzdem irgendwie idiomatisch, das weiß ich nicht. Dann hätte der Fragesteller aber erklären sollen, warum er gerade diese Formulierung gewählt hat und wie das die Antwort beeinflussen soll. Meine Einschätzung der Frage wurde hier anscheinend geteilt. Meine Antwort finde ich inzwischen auch nicht mehr so amüsant wie sie gemeint war.